File `multirow.sty' not found. \usepackage
I am trying to execute this line of code(below) and getting the error above
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
Please assist

Welcome to TeX.SE. Hope your question not related with your subject, please post your code as MWE

If a package is missing, you usually should install it. Because of the tags, it seems, that you are using MiKTeX. So you should use the MiKTeX Console to install multirow.
